# What is this stair trim part called?

Tags: trim, stairs

I was wondering what this part of stair trim that the arrow points to is referred to as.  It is like a faceplate on the side of stairs, inverse of a baseboard.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it's structural (the tread/risers are supported by it), it's called a stringer.

If it's not structural, it's called skirting (or simply a skirt).

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [Source (PDF)](http://www.bayerbuilt.com/Resources/Installation/Stair%20Parts/Adding%20Skirts,%20Treads,%20and%20Risers.pdf)

Comment: not structural, simply decorative